# Как оценить, насколько цвет различим на белом фоне?

Tags: алгоритм, цвета

Вывожу на странице образцы красок в виде кружков разного цвета. Чтобы светлые тона не сливались с фоном страницы, добавляю им серую окантовку. Хочу, чтобы PHP сам определял, какие цвета обводить, а какие нет.

Но как по HEX-коду цвета определить, насколько он сольётся с белым фоном? Например, у кругов `#fcf` и `#ddf` границу разглядеть легко, а в `#ffc` и `#dfd` надо всматриваться, хотя буквы в этих кодах те же самые ;) Что надо посчитать и с чем сравнить?

```css
.samples,
.titles {
  clear: left;
}
.samples > div,
.titles > div {
  float: left;
  margin: 12px;
}
.samples > div {
  border-radius: 18px;
  height: 36px;
  width: 36px;
}
.titles > div {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', serif;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 36px;
}
.titles:first-child,
.titles > div:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div class="titles">
  <div>ddf</div>
  <div>fdd</div>
  <div>eee</div>
  <div>dfd</div>
  <div>fcf</div>
  <div>cff</div>
  <div>ffc</div>
</div>
<div class="samples">
  <div style="background: #ddf"></div>
  <div style="background: #fdd"></div>
  <div style="background: #eee"></div>
  <div style="background: #dfd"></div>
  <div style="background: #fcf"></div>
  <div style="background: #cff"></div>
  <div style="background: #ffc"></div>
</div>
<div class="titles">
  <div>89</div>
  <div>91</div>
  <div>94</div>
  <div>97</div>
  <div>88</div>
  <div>97</div>
  <div>99</div>
  <div>L (%, Lab)</div>
</div>
<div class="titles">
  <div>93</div>
  <div>93</div>
  <div>93</div>
  <div>93</div>
  <div>90</div>
  <div>90</div>
  <div>90</div>
  <div>L (%, HSL)</div>
</div>
<div class="titles">
  <div>240</div>
  <div>0</div>
  <div>0</div>
  <div>120</div>
  <div>300</div>
  <div>180</div>
  <div>60</div>
  <div>H (&deg;, HSL)</div>
</div>
```

**UPD**. Добавил в сниппет значения `Lightness` по модели HSL. [Считал здесь](https://codepen.io/pankajparashar/pen/oFzIg) и [здесь](http://serennu.com/colour/hsltorgb.php). При одинаковых значениях выглядит по-разному.

**UPD 2**. Добавил значения `Hue` из HSL.

**UPD 3**. Добавил `Lightness` из Lab. [Считал здесь](https://colorscheme.ru/color-converter.html). Отсортировал по **L**ab внутри групп с одинаковыми hs**L**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Переведите цвет в [HSL](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL) и смотрите насколько L близок к 100% Более точно оценить близость к белому, с учетом усредненного субъективного восприятия цвета человеком, позволит цветовая модель LAB, но там пересчеты посложнее. Скорее всего это будет излишним

Comment: Спасибо! У `#ddffdd` и `#ddddff` [насчитал](https://codepen.io/pankajparashar/pen/oFzIg) одинаковый L в 93%. У `#ffffcc` и `#ffccff` - тоже, одинаковый, в 90%. Что-то ещё нужно учесть.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky Могу ошибаться, кажется, человек видит зеленый как самый светлый цвет, синий - темнее, красный еще темнее. Соответственно можно внести поправку в зависимости от H. Чем дальше от 120°, тем темнее

Comment: Интересная гипотеза, спасибо!

Comment: @GlebKemarsky кстати можете посмотреть на https://colorscheme.ru/color-converter.html цвета #ddf, #dfd и #fdd в LAB. Обратите внимание на значение L. Похоже в предыдущем комментарии я перепутал: синий "темнее" красного.

Comment: Добавил в сниппет значения Lightness из Lab. Отсортировал по Lab внутри групп с одинаковыми hsL.